# Defining various types of multiplication in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How to define 3 different multiplications in the ring (where the '+' operation is the symmetric difference) , that will make the ring
1) Euclidian ring
2) Not having a 1-element
3) Noncommutative?

Comment: I guess you're asking for different multiplications on the same additive group that give rise to different rings.  It would be easier to answer if your told us what the group is.  I guess the operation is symmetric difference.  What is the undelying set?

Comment: @saulspatz group of sets

Comment: For 1) you can even make it a field, assuming I understand what is being asked.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft using what kind of operation ?

Comment: Just take a small set and check all the options.